# Adding Signature to Email Outlook

Tags: vb.net, outlook

Hey I am trying to add my default signature to an auto generated email the only way I have been able to do it is to use the .Display(Mailitem) and take the Signature from this.

I was wondering if there is any other way to do this that does not involve displaying anything.

```
If sEmailAddress.Contains("@") Then
    Dim objOutlook As Object
    Dim objMailMessage1 As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim signature As String
    objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    objMailMessage1 = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)
    With objMailMessage1
        .To = "richard@Sortmypc.co.uk"
        .Display(objMailMessage1)
        '  .Close()
        signature = .HTMLBody
        .HTMLBody = "<p>" & sEmailGreeting & " " & sLeadName & "</p>" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "<p> Many Thanks for your enquiry, I can confirm our fee to carry out the Home Report would be " & "£" & sHomeReportTotal & " including VAT.</p>" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "<p> We provide Home Reports at a time to suit you with early morning, evening and weekend appointments. <b> We have availability this week/weekend </b> and are more than happy to have a chat whenever is convenient with you and talk you through the home report process. </b>" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "<p><font color=red> Our team of in-house RICS qualified Surveyors </font> who all have local knowledge and provide a professional service.  The Home Report Company also prides itself on a quick turnaround, so unlike some traditional chartered surveying practice we also ensure that all reports are with our clients within 2 working days.</P>" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "<p>Fully insured and regulated by RICS, we understand that selling your home can be an expensive and stressful time and we want to take some of that pressure away from you. So that is why we are open from early in the morning until late in the evening as well as at the weekends so if you have any questions regarding your Home Report then there is someone here to answer those questions.</p>" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "<p>We also understand Home Report Costs can be expensive and that is why we are one of the most competitive in the market.</p>" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "<p>Once again we thank you for your enquiry, and if you have any questions please let me know</P>" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "<p>Look forward to hearing from you.</p>" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "<p>Kind Regards </p>" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "<p>Louise</p>" & "<p>" & signature & "</p>"
        .Subject = "Scottish Home Reports quote -" & sLeadName

        '  .Display()
        '  .Save()
        .Send()
        sEmailSent = "Good Evening " & sLeadName & "" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Many Thanks for your enquiry, I can confirm our fee to carry out the Home Report would be " & "£" & sHomeReportTotal & " including VAT." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "We provide Home Reports at a time to suit you with early morning, evening and weekend appointments.  We have availability this week/weekend and are more than happy to have a chat whenever is convenient with you and talk you through the home report process." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Our team of in-house RICS qualified Surveyors who all have local knowledge and provide a professional service.  The Home Report Company also prides itself on a quick turnaround, so unlike some traditional chartered surveying practice we also ensure that all reports are with our clients within 2 working days." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Fully insured and regulated by RICS, we understand that selling your home can be an expensive and stressful time; and we want to take some of that pressure away from you. So that is why we are open from early in the morning until late in the evening as well as at the weekends so if you have any questions regarding your Home Report then there is someone here to answer those questions." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "We also understand Home Report Costs can be expensive and that is why we are one of the most competitive in the market." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Once again we thank you for your enquiry, and if you have any questions please let me know" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Look forward to hearing from you." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Kind Regards" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Louise"
    End With
    SaveLead()
End If
```

Answer (score -1):

If you create a signature in Outlook it will save three files (HTM, TXT and RTF) into:

```
 C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures
```

You can use the following code to get the signature content:

```
 Function GetBoiler(ByVal sFile As String) As String
  Dim fso As Object
  Dim ts As Object
  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Set ts = fso.GetFile(sFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
  GetBoiler = ts.readall
  ts.Close
 End Function
```

See [Insert Outlook Signature in mail](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/signature.htm) for more information and sample code.

Comment: this way is not being in the images

Comment: Is there anyway to get the image threw aswell @EnugneAstafiev

Comment: Downvoted - the code is VBA (Visual Basic for Applications) and not VB.NET (Visual Basic .NET) as the question's code and tag clearly present.